Problem in uplodaing files to API through Blazor Frontend project
I have an issue when i try to pass files from my frontend to api project
i am using mud blazor file upload
    <MudFileUpload T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>"
               Accept=".png, .jpg"
               FilesChanged="UploadPhotosAsync"
               MaximumFileCount="100"
               Class="me-1"
               Disabled="@(IsUploadingForbidden())">
    <ActivatorContent>
        <MudButton Disabled="@(IsUploadingForbidden())"
                   Variant="Variant.Filled"
                   Color="Color.Success"
                   StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CloudUpload">
            Select Photos
        </MudButton>
    </ActivatorContent>
    </MudFileUpload>

my frontend code:
    public async Task UploadPhotosAsync(IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> browserFiles)
    {
     using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

     foreach (var browserFile in browserFiles)
     {
         var fileStream = browserFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 10 * 1024 *     1024); // e.g., 10 MB limit

         var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

         streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(browserFile.ContentType);

         streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
         {
             FileName = browserFile.Name,
             Name = "files" // This should match the name used in the backend parameter
         };

         content.Add(streamContent, "files", browserFile.Name);
     }

     await GalleryService.UploadPhotos(SelectedYear, SelectedEvent, content);
     }

my service:
 public async Task<object?> UploadPhotos(string year, string eventName, MultipartFormDataContent files)
 {
     try
     {
         HttpResponseMessage httpResponse =
              await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{RequestBaseUrl}/upload-photos?year={year}&eventName={eventName}", files);

         var x = httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(
             await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) : null;

         return httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(
             await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) : null;
     }
     catch(Exception ex) 
     {
         return null;
     }
 }


API:

    [HttpPost("upload-photos")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhotos(string year, string eventName,     [FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
    {
    // Validate inputs
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(year) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventName))
    {
        return BadRequest("Both year and event name must be provided.");
    }

    if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No files provided for upload.");
    }

    try
    {
        // Call the service to upload the photos
        await galleryService.UploadPhotosAsync(year, eventName, files);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Return a 400 Bad Request with the error message if upload fails
        return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
    }

    // Return a success message after upload
    return Ok(new { message = $"Files uploaded successfully to the event '{eventName}'    in the year '{year}'." });
    }


I have tried modifying header and using stream and problem is still there, when i call the api with files it just doesnt dont anything, i tried in postman and it works fine with any number of files, sometimes my above code works when i send only 1 file, the API breakpoint of UploadPhotos hit, I dont know what is happening

what is the size of the files you upload from the browser? have you checked headers? analyze the request by using the fiddler tool to get more detail
